# Request from GC ML Engine to GC AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I have to send a request from GC ML Engine to GC AppEngine. Also, I've configured the firewall in the AppEngine and it does not allow IPs except IPs from the whitelist. I can't find a way to know GC ML Engine static IP. Actually, is it exists? If not - could you please can help me find another way to configure security on the GC AppEngine?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you attempt to achieve? App Engine instances are not accessible through firewalls and via IP addresses, there are not meant to. The simplest approach for communicating with your App Engine service is to send targeted HTTP requests, where the URL includes the name or ID of a resource. This is the designed way to access your App Engine resources. You may get more insight on the "Communicating Between Your Services" [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/communicating-between-services).

Comment: @George
Yes, it's the way I use. But my AppEngine firewall configured to deny all requests except whitelist. ML Engine instance doesn't have static IP, so I can't add it to the whitelist.

Comment: It would prove helpful if you add more detail on the need for a request from GC ML Engine to GC AppEngine. Can this request be directed to one of the services offered by your app? Could you create a dedicated service, if not present?